# Seeking photographs of "climber's hunch"

Tags: climbing, bouldering

I couldn't find any pictures of this online. (There were some simulated hunches, but no pictures of people with bad posture.)

Comment: Is [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12324/muscle-imbalances-related-to-indoor-rock-climbing-bouldering-and-ways-to-fix-the) the type of hunching you're talking about?

Comment: Most climbers I know have considerbly better posture than the average person. Climbing places considerable strain on core muscle groups. The stronger your core the better your posture.

Comment: I've [added an answer to that question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/18187/10169) as, for me, it's nonesense

Comment: The question over on fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12324 has a lot of info on this. Asking for photos here is off topic.